# Открыть новое окно с применением стилей в PySide2

Tags: python, pyqt5, анимация, pyside2, qpropertyanimation

У меня в приложении по кнопке открываются новые окна. 
Мне хотелось бы, чтобы эти окна открывались как-нибудь "красиво". Ну слева выплывали или сверху, или с задержкой какой-то.

Не могу нигде подобных примеров найти. Может кто подскажет, как сделать подобные стили для дочерних окон? Спасибо.

Привожу простой пример открытия нового окна

**UI_test.py**

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from random import randint
class Ui_Form(object):
def setupUi(self, Form):
    Form.resize(1300, 700)
    self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.layout.setSpacing(0)
    self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
    self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    self.layout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
    self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex)
    item1 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/settings.png'),'CamSettings', self.listWidget)
    item2 = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(QtGui.QIcon('icons/explore.png'),'Explore', self.listWidget)
    item1.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))
    item2.setSizeHint(QtCore.QSize(10, 60))
    item1.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    item2.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    label2= QtWidgets.QLabel('Это страница 2')
    label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    label2.setStyleSheet('background: rgb(%d, %d, %d); margin: 50px;' % (
        randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255), randint(0, 255)))
    create_tiff_but = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Create TIFF')
    create_tiff_but.setObjectName('createTifBut')
    create_tiff_but.setFixedSize(200, 70)
    create_tiff_but.clicked.connect(Form.create_tiff)
    image_panel_buttons = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    image_panel_buttons.addWidget(create_tiff_but)
    image_panel_buttons_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    image_panel_buttons_frame.setLayout(image_panel_buttons)
    main_first_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    main_first_box.addWidget(image_panel_buttons_frame)
    first_container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    first_container.setLayout(main_first_box)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(first_container)
    self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label2)
    Form.setLayout(self.layout)
```

**app.py**

```
import sys
import os
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from UI_test import Ui_Form
from create_tiff import Create_TIFF

class App(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

    def create_tiff(self):
        # функция открытия диалогового окна для создания tiff
        self.ct = Create_TIFF()
        self.ct.displayInfo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = App()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**create_tiff.py**

```
import os
import json
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore

class Create_TIFF(QtWidgets.QWidget):
#модуль с диалоговым окном для создания tiff файла
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Create_TIFF, self).__init__(parent)
    self.setFixedWidth(400)
    self.setFixedHeight(220)
    self.setObjectName('modalTIFF')
    self.setWindowTitle('Create TIFF')
    self.json=None
    self.path=None
    button_json = QtWidgets.QPushButton("JSON")
    button_json.setObjectName('modalJSONBtn')
    button_json.setFixedWidth(90)
    button_img = QtWidgets.QPushButton("IMG PATH")
    button_img.setObjectName('modalImgPathBtn')
    button_img.setFixedWidth(90)
    button_tiff = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Create TIFF")
    button_tiff.setObjectName('modalCrtTIFFBtn')
    button_tiff.setFixedSize(200, 70)
    json_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Название json')
    self.name_json= QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.name_json.setFixedWidth(160)
    path_label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Путь к файлу')
    self.name_path = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
    self.name_path.setFixedWidth(160)
    first_h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    first_h_box.addWidget(json_label)
    first_h_box.addWidget(self.name_json)
    first_h_box.addWidget(button_json)
    second_h_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    second_h_box.addWidget(path_label)
    second_h_box.addWidget(self.name_path)
    second_h_box.addWidget(button_img)
    first_h_box_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    first_h_box_frame.setLayout(first_h_box)
    second_h_box_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    second_h_box_frame.setLayout(second_h_box)
    vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(first_h_box_frame)
    vbox.addWidget(second_h_box_frame)
    vbox.addWidget(button_tiff,alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
    self.setLayout(vbox)
    resolution = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    self.move((resolution.width() / 2) - (self.frameSize().width() / 2),
              (resolution.height() / 2) - (self.frameSize().height() / 2))

def displayInfo(self):
    self.show()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует открытие новые окна по нажатию кнопки.

Comment: добавил простой пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `QPropertyAnimation` анимирует свойства Qt.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html

```
import sys 
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class SecondWidget(QWidget):
    closed = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.closeBtn = QPushButton('Close')
        self.closeBtn.clicked.connect(self._close)
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.closeBtn, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignBottom)
        
        self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self, b'windowOpacity')
        self.animation.setDuration(1500)       

    def _close(self):
        self.animation.stop()
        self.animation.finished.connect(self.close)
        self.animation.setStartValue(1)
        self.animation.setEndValue(0)
        self.animation.start() 

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closed.emit()        

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(128, 228, 128, 128))


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(350, 250)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint)

        self.openBtn = QPushButton('open')
        self.openBtn.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)
        self.label = QLabel("Hello World")
        
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.openBtn, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
        layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, alignment=Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
     
    def open_dialog(self):
        x, y = self.geometry().x(), self.geometry().y()
        self.dialog = QWidget()
        self.box = SecondWidget()
        self.box.closed.connect(self.do_something)
        self.box.show()

        self.animation_2  = QPropertyAnimation(self.box,  b"geometry")
        self.animation_2.setDuration(7000)
        self.animation_2.setStartValue(self.geometry())    
        self.animation_2.setEndValue(QRect(x+400, y, 350, 250))
        self.animation_2.setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve.OutBounce)
        self.animation_2.start()

    def do_something(self):
        self.label.setText("Closed")
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.fillRect(self.rect(), QColor(128, 128, 228, 228))
    
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Это то , что мне нужно